# How to get Rid of the JSON Error in Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, firefox

My Response Header is

```
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  81
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Mon, 26 Aug 2013 06:35:53 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.7`
```

And The Request Header is

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  31
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  USERNAMEEMAIL=shan%40atlos.com; PHPSESSID=8asm46iltcqc9oahsbaaap1c16
Host    localhost
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://localhost/test/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest`
```

i am getting error in firefox "Not Well Formed" what is the problem in this.
i am getting the data correctly in json form but it show also error that is very annoying

Java Script Code to Make Request
[GetTopNotification](http://engineers-web.com/F09/notitfications.js)
And Uses a Class for make Ajax Request is
[Workspace](http://engineers-web.com/F09/work-space.js)

Comment: Post the JSON that is giving the error, please.

Comment: @MikeW i am getting this in response
`{"success":"true","friends":"0","notifications":"0","messages":"0","reirect":"0"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reponse-header is incorrect.

```
if(headers_sent()) die('Should not output data before json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data_for_json);
exit;
```

Also, nothing should be sent before the json, and nothing after it either.

---

In response to comment below:

Somewhere in your php-code you're outputting json. However, as stated, your reponse header is incorrect: the `Content-type` part should be set to `application/json`; the above code does just that. A line-by line walktrough:

1. Checks if you did not already send anything and die if you did
2. Set the `Content-type` part of your response header to the appropriate mime-type
3. Output the json (as it currently is, should be fine)
4. exit;

---

More update irt comments

You're creating your json string manually: something i can wholeheartedly advice against, use an array or object and then use json_encode to create you json.
I also added output_buffering over your code, just in case.

Give it a try, new code is [here](http://ideone.com/h0yiNp)

---

Update three

In work-space.js Replace this line

```
self.responseValue = self.getValueFromResponse( jqXHR );
```

With this

```
if(type != 'xml') self.responseValue = data;
else self.responseValue = self.getValueFromResponse( jqXHR );
```

save it, clear the cache, and try again.

Comment: What is this and what to do with these?

Comment: Not enough room in comments, so i updated the answer; hope this clears it up for you

Comment: Same problem still should i post link of that php file in text form so you can see that file? @vollie

Comment: http://engineers-web.com/F09/topnotification.txt
here is that file in which i get response in json form

Comment: this is php file it give as response in json form that i get through javaScript/JQuery Ajax call and append in html page works fine but showing error in firefox "Not well Formed" and because of this error some functionality stops withOut any message but i know that its stop

Comment: Timestamp: 8/26/2013 12:55:09 PM
Error: not well-formed
Source File: http://localhost/test/
Line: 1, Column: 1
Source Code:
{"success":true,"friends":0,"notifications":"0","messages":0,"reirect":0}
Getting This

Comment: Ok, leaves me two questions; 1: please post the javascript making the request as well (just edit your post). and 2: Where does this error appear (Firebug, WEbdevelopertoolbar,...)

Comment: i have edit question and like the files that i use and i am chaek from WebDeveloper ToolBar

Comment: Holy something. That's like some library on top of jQuery if i'm not mistaken. Anyway, it's success callback calls `getValueFromResponse` which calls `getResponseXML` which parses the responseText as text/xml, which is something we do not want. Once more, an Update is inserted above.

Comment: but how is it i am not understand that

Comment: because the WS class parsed the result as XML regardless of specified type by always calling the `getResponseXML` function on success. As you can imagine, a JSON string is *not* valid XML and as such you got an error.